# android web button load more

Tags: javascript, android, parsing

I have an app, that parses data from the website. The website does not have any API. At the end of page there is a button "load more". This is the code of this button:

```
<a href="#" id="js-index_load_more_posts" class="b-load_more_posts_button" onclick="moreHandler.loadPosts(this, {'load_more' : true}); return false;">Load more</a>
```

How can I call this button from my app to load more data to parse it from the page later?

And what I should read about that for understanding this. Maybe some keywords for google search, because I didn't find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse out what the javaScript does, specifically `moreHandler.loadPosts`. The easiest approach is to pull this site up in Chrome and use the JavaScript console to see what url requests are made to pull the additional information.

Comment: Console shows nothing. Only some errors about loading images. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In Chrome, click on Tools/JavaScript console, then select the "Network" tab. Pull up your page and click the "more" button, check the console. If it doesn't load anything else, then the "more" text is already in the page you initially loaded -- look at the page-source, especially at DIV tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `WebView` control to load the content, you can execute the following `JavaScript` code in it:

```
moreHandler.loadPosts(this, {'load_more' : true}); return false;
```

By doing something like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:moreHandler.loadPosts(this, {'load_more' : true}); return false;");
```

Make sure to enable `JavaScript` in your `WebView` control:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: So you should find out how does the `onclick` handler on that page work and what URL does it load. Then you can parse the content retrieved from that `URL` as @323go suggested.